# Checking for nil Core Data property results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: core-data, swift

I have a simple `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
@objc class MyModel: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var myProperty: String
}
```

However, the following code:

```
var model = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as MyModel

assert(model != nil) // passes

if model.myProperty != nil { //crashes
    println("not nil")
}
```

crashes at `if model.myProperty != nil` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Why is this happening? This only started happening with Beta 5, and worked properly with Beta 4.

The above class was automatically generated using Xcode, so they did not add a `?` to the end of the property. However, manually adding a `?` to the end of the property does resolve the issue (`@NSManaged var myProperty: String?`).

My question is, why doesn't Xcode automatically add the question mark to make it optional if it is marked as such in the schema, and why was this not an issue in previous betas?

Comment: Why would myProperty ever be nil if it is not an optional?

Comment: @Jeff It is optional, at least is marked as such in the schema. However, the above class was automatically generated using Xcode.

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake. Interesting reading your update that adding the question mark fixed it. Perhaps flag an issue with the bug reporter.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  I'd file a radar on it

Answer (score 7):

To make it work you should do 2 things :

1) in the `NSManagedObject` subclass add ? to made the property optional

```
@objc class MyModel: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var myProperty: String? // <-- add ? here
}
```

2) in your implementation as suggested in the previous answer

```
if let aProperty = model.myProperty? {
    // do something with aProperty
}
```

Note that if you forgot to add ? in the `NSManagedObject` subclass you we have compilation error.

Comment: The auto-generated NSManagedObject Swift class files fail to annotate optional properties with ? in the version of Xcode I was using. Watch out for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the pattern Apple suggests in its *Swift Programming Language* guide is

```
if let aProperty = model.myProperty? {
    // do something with aProperty
}
```